# Convert specific columns in CSV to dictionary and certain logic - Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

`List A` contains values:

```
abc11  198
abc12  178
abc11  198
abc13  123 and so on
```

I have written a function to remove all the duplicates and store the unique abc values in `List B = ['abc11', 'abc12', 'abc13', ... ]`

A CSV file contains:

```
abc11  bvc  ex  123  456  somestuffhere
abc11  bvc  ex  456  476  somestuffhere
abc12  bvc  ex  173  426  somestuffhere
abc12  bvc  ex  426  496  somestuffhere
abc13  bvc  ex  143  796  somestuffhere
abc13  bvc  ex  743  896  somestuffhere
```

I want the zeroth column values as keys and the third and the fourth columns as values, only the minimum(or the third) and the maximum(or the fourth) values when the keys are the same. I am also not sure if it is best if the values are as a list inside a dictionary as I need to check these values with another list later on.

`{'abc11':['123','476'],'abc12':['173','496'],'abc13':['143','896']}`

I am trying to match the match values in `list A` and if the keys in the dictionary match with `List B`, then I need to check if the numerical value in `List A` (for the corresponding `abc` value) is between that specific `abc` value in the dictionary. If yes, I want to append that `abc` and its value in a separate list. I have done the same using lists in the code below, but I want to store the csv file values as a dictionary and perform the operations.

My code so far:

```
# abc_value                      #list_A
# list_no_rep                    #list_B

match_list = []
with open('new.csv', 'r') as file_open:
lines = csv.reader(file_open, delimiter = '\t')

for row in lines:
    for abcs in list_no_rep:
        if row[0] == abcs:
            for value_row in abc_value:
                if row[3] <= value_row[1] <= row[4]:
                    match_list.append(value_row)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to fix the indent errors above so others can help.  Also check out [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: @N1B4 : I have done the same. Thanks. I have also made it more readable.

Comment: @quarters what's the expected value in match_list ? The CSV contains "abc11" in two rows. Did you pick [smaller value in 3rd, larger value in 4th col] or something else?